# Hbox horizontalScrollPosition not working

Tags: apache-flex, hbox

I am applying hb.horizontalScrollPosition = value and it does not work with horizonalScrollPolicy = on/off. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When exactly are you setting the scroll position relative to loading the content?  Perhaps the content isn't measured yet.  Try using callLater to wait a frame before setting the scroll position.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for the reply. I am setting on the button click event after the content is loaded.